# How can I condense calls to create lyrics into a single variable call?

Tags: lilypond, lyrics

I am working on a template for SATB Vocal hymn.
To show the lyrics underneath the Soprano line, I use the following.

```
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
        \set stanza = "1." \small \verseOne
      }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
        \set stanza = "2." \small \verseTwo
      }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
        \set stanza = "3." \small \verseThree
      }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
        \set stanza = "4." \small \verseFour
      }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
        \set stanza = "5." \small \verseFive
      }
```

It works well inside a `\score`. I can see 5 stanzas in this hymn.

My question is, is it possible to combine all these 15 lines for showing lyrics into a single variable? Say `\allVerses` which replaces these 15 lines?

I tried ...

```
allVerses = {
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
      \set stanza = "1." \small \verseOne
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
      \set stanza = "2." \small \verseTwo
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
      \set stanza = "3." \small \verseThree
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
      \set stanza = "4." \small \verseFour
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
      \set stanza = "5." \small \verseFive
    }
  }
```

... but this method only display the first stanza in the SATB song.

So, is there a way for showing all lyrics using a single variable?

Thank you!!

Comment: Are these verses supposed to appear directly under one-another (as the music repeats)?

Comment: Correct. And I wish I knew how to attach a screenshot here...

Comment: You should be able to attach a screenshot with the [image icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqVzn.png) in the editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re almost there, all you have to do is to wrap the various `\new Lyrics` blocks in double chevrons `<<` & `>>`.  This will make each of these occur *simultaneously* rather than sequentially.

```
allVerses = {
    <<
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
            \set stanza = "1." \small \verseOne
        }
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
            \set stanza = "2." \small \verseTwo
        }
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
            \set stanza = "3." \small \verseThree
        }
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
            \set stanza = "4." \small \verseFour
        }
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "Soprano" {
            \set stanza = "5." \small \verseFive
        }
    >>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the chevrons. The stanzas print out beautifully.

Comment: Remark: The sequential music `{ ... }` around `<< ... >>` is not necessary.

Comment: @Lazy. Thanks and noted. That's a habit from C++.